# Unable to sign JWT Token programmatically with LexikBundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm implementing Lexik JWT library with Sf 4.1.
In my case I have to create a JWT Token when needed for several applications through custom authenticator.
I have followed the lexik documentation, however I am facing an issue for couple of hours for signing my token.
The only thing different than casual case : I use doctrine-odm insteand of doctrine-orm for using MongoDb.

Here the files :

security.yaml :

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        anonymous: ~
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
        remember_me:
            secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\GuardAuthenticator\LoginFormAuthenticator

access_control:
     - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml :

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
pass_phrase: '%env(resolve:JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
token_ttl: 3600
```

LoginFormAuthenticator.php (onAuthenticationSuccess method) :

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param TokenInterface $token
 * @param string $providerKey
 *
 * @return null|JsonResponse
 */
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(
    Request $request,
    TokenInterface $token,
    $providerKey
): ?JsonResponse {
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $token->getUser();
    $apiToken = $this->jwtTokenManager->create($user);

    $user->setApiToken($apiToken);
    $this->documentManager->persist($user);
    $this->documentManager->flush();

    return new JsonResponse(['Authorization' => $apiToken]);
}
```

private.pem :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,F05739F4D47EE90DADA678BA60000AE4
<sensitive data>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I tried to inspect parameters passed to create or sign method in vendor :

- The "key" parameter passed is the path string to the file, and it is not working, getting "
  Unable to create a signed JWT from the given configuration." error

Do you have any piece of advice to help me please ?

Comment: Do you have to pass in the file or the data from the file? If the latter, try using `secret_key: '%env(file:resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'` to extract the data from the resolved file name. See also: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html#environment-variable-processors

Comment: @dbrumann I followed the documentation, and it just specify to set `'%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'`. I try with 'file' before and give you a feed back. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that does not work. I have this error : `Env "file:resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY" not found: /var/www/html/project/config/jwt/private.pem does not exist.`
However I check the path of the private key file, and it is the correct path.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct, including the right case, e.g. no `JWT` instead of `jwt`? What happens if you run the console command `cat /var/www/html/project/config/jwt/private.pem` does it display the content?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I've check with cat, vim and ls and commands return me the result as expected. I've also check the permissions that are correct, set as 744.

Comment: I managed, thank you @dbrumann ! The problem was in rights permission actually ! It needed the execution rights of course, so with 755 rights, everything looks fine ! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to create the jwt token

```html
 
public function getTokenUser(JWTTokenManagerInterface $JWTManager,ManagerRegistry $mr,UserPasswordHasherInterface $hasher)
{
    $em = $mr->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => 'user']);
    if($hasher->isPasswordValid($user, 'user')){
        $token = $JWTManager->create($user);
        return new JsonResponse(['token' => $token]);
    }
    return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Invalid credentials'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).